# initialize "array field"

Tags: c#

My class contains such field:

```
class AAA {
    private Queue<DateTime>[] times = new Queue<DateTime>[10];
    ....
```

As I understand this is initializes array of `null`. Do I have options other than writing `for` loop in constructor?

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize this array using an array initializer like this :

```
private Queue<DateTime>[] times = new Queue<DateTime>[10]
                                  {
                                      new Queue<DateTime>(), 
                                      new Queue<DateTime>(), 
                                      new Queue<DateTime>(), 
                                      new Queue<DateTime>(), 
                                      new Queue<DateTime>(), 
                                      new Queue<DateTime>(), 
                                      new Queue<DateTime>(), 
                                      new Queue<DateTime>(), 
                                      new Queue<DateTime>(), 
                                      new Queue<DateTime>(), 
                                  };
```

or with whatever values you need inside it. You can use this shorthand too :

```
private Queue<DateTime>[] times = new[]
                                 {
                                     new Queue<DateTime>(), 
                                     ..... 
                                     new Queue<DateTime>(), 
                                 };
```